# Is there anyway to mock Emitter in Quarkus?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-kafka, quarkus, quarkus-reactive, smallrye-reactive-messaging

Hi I tried to test my producer logic and I just wanted to @InjectMock an Emitter but it throw an error something like :

```
Caused by: jakarta.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Emitter
```

Any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive Messaging channels are based on CDI extensions, so you cannot inject a mock directly. But you can use the [`InMemoryConnector`](http://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/4.10.0/concepts/testing/) to replace the connector implementation and test your producer logic.

Using the in-memory connector, you can get the sink with the channel name of your emitter and assert on received objects.

You can also check https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#testing-without-a-broker for more information.

Comment: Hi  Ozan thank you!, it works using InMemoryConnection

Comment: Hi @Ozan Günalp can we use in-memory connector in native application ? as my understanding this test only for JVM application ?

Comment: That's true, you cannot use in-memory connector while testing a native application.   You'd do tests closer to integration-tests with a packaged application.